# Use playerctl in systemd-nspawn container

Tags: dbus, chroot-jail

When I launch a web browser in a systemd-nspawn container, playerctl commands don't work to play and pause multimedia, though they work for browsers outside of the container. Is there an environment variable or directory binding that I might be missing to allow playerctl to interact with applications in a chroot or container?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

playerctl contacts your music players through the D-Bus *session bus*<sup>1</sup> which is accessed through a Unix socket. Typically there's one per UID, and its address is expected to be found in `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS`.

It might be possible to bind the bus socket into the container, so that the web browser could connect to it, but I would *not* recommend doing so: there are many services available on your session bus that a malicious program could abuse (e.g. asking gnome-shell to eval() arbitrary JavaScript code).

The *Flatpak* sandboxing system (which uses namespace-based containers just like nspawn does) provides a generic [D-Bus proxy](https://github.com/flatpak/xdg-dbus-proxy) which can be configured to only allow specific bus "service names" to be contacted by the sandboxed app (or owned by it). I would recommend running your web browser through Flatpak if you want to sandbox it.

If that's not possible, then manually set up xdg-dbus-proxy to let the nspawn container own the necessary `org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.chromium.*` service names without letting it talk to your entire desktop environment.

---

<sup>1</sup> Not to be confused with the system bus.